# How can I clone a remote repo from another machine via ip address

Tags: git, ssh

I've never experienced it before. So, please bear with me.

I have generated a RSA ssh key. I checked it by following.

```
ssh-agent -s

Output
------
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-<12chars-key>/agent.<5-digit no>; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=<5-digit no>; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid <5-digit no>;
```

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I run the above command and added the identity from `.ssh/id_rsa` private key.

I'm on an ubuntu.

When I clone from github using this ssh public key,
I can. But from other remote machine using ip address, I can't and output the following error.

```
Cloning into 'myreponame'...
myusername@<ip address>: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

I used following command.

```
git clone git+ssh://<ip ADDRESS>/PATH/TO/GIT/REPO
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that the output from `ssh-agent -s` must be passed to an `eval` so that it takes effect in the shell you're running. Note further that on macOS you *should not* run `ssh-agent` yourself as logging in on the mac starts a master ssh agent that is already there in each terminal window you create; however, on Linux you generally *should* run `ssh-agent` yourself, although there are exceptions depending on how you set things up for yourself and which Linux you install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now working!

The correct command to use is

```
git clone ssh://git@<ip address>/PATH/TO/REMOTE/REPO
```